# range.toString() truncates last char in javascript keypress event

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, contenteditable

I'm writing a function to parse words inline in a contenteditable div and replace tags (@..., #...) with an anchor tag.  I was firing it on the keyup event, and it worked perfectly.  The problem was that I wanted to replace tags not only after the user hits space, but also after they hit a non-word character.  Since the keyup event only gets access to the key pressed, not the actual character entered, I couldn't recognize punctuation marks.

All I did was change to the keypress event, and now my function leaves off the last character of the tag when creating the anchor.  Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/jwoah12/CcwSt/115/.

wordStart and wordEnd seem to have correct values, but j.toString() produces the wrong result.

Thanks,
Jared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

On keypress, get the character entered, save it in a variable.
On keyup, look at the value in the variable, if it's the punctuation you are looking for, execute your replacement logic.

Comment: Thanks!  This does the trick.  However, I'd like to not have to use keyup at all if possible because if you type too fast, the keyup event is sometimes missed.